# Im new to android webview and using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

I am trying to get my android app to work with JavaScript. I have enabled JavaScript. And i have no idea why this is not working all the research i have done says it should. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my Java code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    setProgressBarVisibility(true); 

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


    final Activity activity = this;
}



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        webview.goBack();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    webview = new WebView(this);      
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
        @Override  
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
        {  
          view.loadUrl(url);  
          return true;  
        }  
      });                 
    setContentView(webview);      
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/droid/mobile_index.html");
    return true;}
```

and here is the JavaScript i am trying to be able to interface with.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function reply_click(clicked_name)
   {
   var clicked_name;
document.location="http://www.example.com/droid/updatescore.php?location=" +    clicked_name;

     }
     </script>
```

I have a php table that is created dynamically, And there for the cells will not always have the same name. I am using JavaScript With DOM to get the variable, and pass it to a new webpage as a variable inside a URL. It works Perfect on my computer browser However not on my phone. I have enable JavaScript however its not working. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are pretending exactly with onCreateOptionsMenu. That would be the code that should be in **onCreate**

That way, you should set the *WebViewClient* in the **onCreate** method.

Then, your code should be like:

```
private static WebView webView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
        @Override  
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
        {  
              return false;  
        }  
      }); 
    setProgressBarVisibility(true); 

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

setContentView(webview);

    final Activity activity = this;
}



@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        webview.goBack();

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    webview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/droid/mobile_index.html");
    return true;
}
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for your comment Regys788880 However that didnt seem to help... Any other ideas. I have been working on this for 3 days now to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial that answered my question hope it can help http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/webview/android-webview-example/